# If there is no way to put a timeout in pandas read_csv, how to proceed?

Tags: python, pandas

The *CSV* files linked to *Google Sheets* if by any chance there is a problem, it can't finish executing the task and stays in the same place for eternity, so I need to add a **timeout** in the attempt to import the *CSV*.

I am currently test the situation with `func-timeout`:

```
from func_timeout import func_timeout, FunctionTimedOut
import pandas as pd

try:
  csv_file = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/XXXX/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'
  df = func_timeout(30, pd.read_csv, args=(csv_file))
except FunctionTimedOut:
  print('timeout')
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

But return this error (which apparently besides not having worked, in the future it will become unusable because there is the *FutureWarning* alert):

```
FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of read_csv except for the argument 'filepath_or_buffer' will be keyword-only.
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
read_csv() takes from 1 to 52 positional arguments but 168 were given
```

When my expected output is:

```
      SS_Id      SS_Match  xGoals_Id xGoals_Match       Bf_Id          Bf_Match
0  10341056  3219 x 65668        NaN            x    31539043  194508 x 5408226
1  10340808   3217 x 3205        NaN            x    31537759  220949 x 1213581
2  10114414   2022 x 1972        NaN            x    31535268  4525642 x 200603
3  10114275  1974 x 39634        NaN            x    31535452  198124 x 6219238
```

I would like some assistance in finding the best solution for my current situation and need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a syntax error here: `args=(csv_file)` which leads to the FutureWarning down the line. You want a singlet (tuple with 1 value) like this: `args=(csv_file, )`

The comma makes the tuple!

(*Riddle: Why did it say you passed 168 arguments?*)

```
# it should work with a proper argument tuple.
df = func_timeout(30, pd.read_csv, args=(csv_file, ))
```

Comment: Hi @creanion (Why did it say you passed 168 arguments?) he read each character from the url as an one argument. Haha

Answer (score 2):

Using the library `func_timeout` is not strictly necessary.
Pandas uses `urllib` to fetch urls and this library wraps the lower level `socket` library which has a timeout parameter. However Pandas doesn't expose that timeout parameter to the user, but you can set it through `socket.setdefaulttimeout` before launching the main program.

So at the beginning define:

```
TIMEOUT_SEC = 10 # default timeount in seconds
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(TIMEOUT_SEC)
import pandas as pd
```

and then your code:

```
try:
  csv_file = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/XXXX/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'
  df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```